# WCF REstful Service Passing user and password on Uri

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf

I do have a WCF RESTful .NET 4.0 service that runs and consumes values #Json from the body of the URI.

the way I invoke my method is the following:

Using Poster, as POST request
http://localhost:25512/JSONService1.svc/CreateItem

Body:

= YOLO

works fine!

but I want to consume the uri as well ,

http://localhost:25512/JSONService1.svc/CreateItem?uid=aaa&pass=111

here is my code

this is on Service1.cs

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "CreateItem",  // ISSUES <<< not sure what to do here
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST")]    

void CreateItem(Stream streamOfData,string uid, string pass);
```

and this the associated code with it , Service1.svc.cs

```
public void CreateItem(Stream streamOfData, string uid, string pass)
{
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamOfData);
        String res = reader.ReadToEnd();
        NameValueCollection coll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(res);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to consume the uri as well"?

Comment: perhaps I should have called it URL instead of URI , I want to Pass/consume the "uid and pass" parameters and use them inside CreateItem method

Comment: Ok so you want to know what the actual URI is when the client sends the request?

Comment: the device "client" will always send the request ended with "?uid=aaa&pass=111" including JSON in the body . However, the project I have so far only accepts the body.

Comment: Got it. So my question is, do you want to know what the full URI is?

Comment: Yes I do want to know the full URI is and how can I parse it in my function... i am bit confused here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the original URI you can do the following:

```
string originalUri = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.RequestUri.OriginalString;
```

You can use the [System.Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.URI%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) class and / or the [HttpUtility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046(v=vs.110).aspx) class to parse the Uri.

To use the [System.Uri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.URI%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) class just pass in the Uri.

```
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://localhost:25512/JSONService1.svc/CreateItem?uid=aaa&pass=111");
```

or in your requirement:

```
Uri myUri = new Uri(originalUri);
```

Then you can examine various pieces of the Uri by using some of the built in properties.

Comment: Thanks =D that helped